# What actually is "Cedar Trail drm driver in DKMS format"?

Tags: linux, xorg, proprietary, display-driver

I know that it is somehow related to the video driver and hardware acceleration, but what **exactly** this driver is? It seems it is not the video driver itself. So, what actually it is and how exactly is related to the video driver?

Before installation it is named **"Cedar Trail drm driver in DKMS format"**. After installation it appears as **"drm driver for the Intel GMA 500"**.

After installing this driver, another driver appears, named **"Intel Cedarview graphics driver"**, that seems to be the real graphics driver.

Both are installed on a netbook with Intel GMA 3650 video adapter. Linux Mint 13.

Comment: I believe it is a driver to support the 'Intel Insider' set of on-chip features. read up on the controversy here: http://blogs.intel.com/technology/2011/01/intel_insider_-_what_is_it_no/ some schmuck from Intel claims its not DRM, but thats just because people don't like DRM.

Comment: Are we sure DRM here doesn't stand for Direct Rendering Manager? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Manager